# Getting Freebase Topics TODAY?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, freebase

So even though Google shut down Freebase, when you ping the YouTube API, it still tags the videos using Freebase IDs.

Is there a place I can go to now, to match these IDs to their topics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Freebase data dumps are [still available](https://developers.google.com/freebase/#freebase-rdf-dumps) or you can use the online Knowledge Graph [Search API](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/) which accepts the same IDs.

e.g. https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?ids=/m/01mpvdt&key=API_KEY&limit=5&indent=True